# Using truffle migrate with Ledger Nano S

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, ledger-nano-s

I am using truffle to develop new contracts and I have successfully deployed contracts to the Rinkeby Testnet directly with truffle. However, this process, like the one using the MainNet, requires geth started with an unlocked account:

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --syncmode "fast" --unlock="0x000-deployer-address-here"
```

Now `truffle migrate` will deploy the Migrations contract and my other contracts with `0x000-deployer-address-here` address as the owner.

My question is if this deployment can be done with a Ledger Nano S address as the owner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [truffle-ledger-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-ledger-provider) for deploying smart contracts with Ledger Wallet.

Usage as follows:

```
var LedgerWalletProvider = require("truffle-ledger-provider");
var infura_apikey = "..."; // set your Infura API key
var ledgerOptions = {
    networkId: 3, // ropsten testnet
    accountsOffset: 0 // we use the first address
};
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        ropsten: {
            provider: new LedgerWalletProvider(ledgerOptions, "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + infura_apikey),
            network_id: 3
        }
    }
};
```